# Changing an image in fixed menu after sliding down in Alpine js

Tags: javascript, html, css, alpine.js

I would like to change the src picture of an image (or use some other technique?) in my fixed menu bar when I scroll down.

Here is my html:

```
<header>
  <a href="/">
    <img src="img1.jpg" width="200px" height="100px">
  </a>
</header>
<main>
...
```

The header is fixed. So it stays on the top of the page during scrolling all the time.

Now, I would like to transition (if that's possible with the Alpine's `x-show.transition` or CSS's `transition`?) when I start scrolling.

So, when I start scrolling the image is starting to get smaller to the new image dimension and then being fade out and fade in replaced with the new image `img2.jpg` with the new dimensions `width="150px"` and `height="80px"`.

How to do that in pure Alpine js?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have any experience with Alpine JS, so i solved this with CSS and standard JS.

Start by giving your img object an id, then add the styling below to the object.

```
#img {
    transition: .5s;
}
```

I used a scroll-listener and checked the scrollvalue.

```
const elem = document.getElementById("img");
window.onscroll = function() {
  if(window.scrollY>=40){
    //user scrolled to the top of the page
    elem.style.height = "80px";
    elem.style.width = "150px";
  } else {
    //user scrolled to the top of the page
    elem.style.height = "100px";
    elem.style.width = "200px";
  }
};
```